# Global.json and running web application

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a new web application using OS X and VS Code from scratch without using any scaffolding tool. My starting point is Scott Allen's tutorial on pluralsight:

https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-core-1-0-fundamentals/table-of-contents

My project structure is:

[image: Project structure]

The `global.json` file contains

```
{
    "projects": [ "src" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2"
    }
}
```

And the `project.json` currently contains

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": false
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {}
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I have run `dnu restore` to get the packages and now I would like to run the web. I need to go to the web app folder and run `dnx web` in order to do so and the app starts

[image: Running web app]

Is it possible to run the application directly from the root folder, not from the web app folder? Is the `global.json` file needed in such setup? And how do I change the hosting environment? I have gone through the documentation, but the hosting environment is only clear when using VS 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply run from the root because there could be multiple projects that are "executable". But you can pass the project to dnx using the `--project/-p` argument.

The environment is set using the `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable.

The global.json file is useful for two things:

1. The `sdk` section is only by VS.
2. The `projects` section is used all the time and it's useful if you have the projects in multiple folders (for example `src` and `test`). If everything is in a single folder, you don't need it.

So, the bare minimum in order to run an web application is:

1. A folder for your project
2. A project.json file
3. A startup file

Comment: I tried the `--project` parameter before but it seems it does not work...I see now the path has to be straight to the file, I used only the path to the directory containing `project.json`. The correct command is: `dnx -p ./src/AndaronWebapp/project.json web`

Comment: Would you also know how to set kestrel to rebuild the code when the files are saved/the code changes? Or should it be an option of the asp core? I know that dnx has a watch command, maybe running that in another bash thread?